# Parsing a String with Regex to Remove Leading #s and Remove Unwanted Chars

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing

I have strings such as this (in PHP):

```
5SGs_FreeDVD_StaticBlock_v2.jpg
30SecondPreview_FLV-600.flv
All Over The World_Click+Countoff_Preview.mp3
```

And I want to end up with these strings:

```
SGs FreeDVD StaticBlock v2
Second Preview FLV 600
All Over The World Click Countoff Preview
```

The are a few rules for my parsing:

1. All LEADING digits should be removed (like the `5` and the `30`)
2. All trailing file types should be removed (like `.jpg`, `.flv`, and `.mp3`)
3. All special characters should be replaced with spaces (like `_` and `-` and `+` )

I am unfamiliar with PHP and don't know the right kind of functions I should be using for this kind of operation.

How would you go about this?

Comment: Are you familiar with Regex?

http://ca1.php.net/preg_replace

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters" ? Special to what? Is it a file name? What OS? What happes when the "string" is `49@#$1=0_-+_-021.jpg.mpg` ?

Comment: Should `Second Preview` be spaced in the final string?  Why?  Why aren't `FreeDVD` and `StaticBlock` space separated then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably easier (and cleaner) to do this in three steps:

```
// remove leading numbers
$str = preg_replace('/^\d+/m', '', $str); 

// remove file extensions
$str = preg_replace('/\.(jpg|flv|mp3)/', '', $ret);

// replace special characters
$str = preg_replace('/[[:punct:]]/', ' ', $ret);
```

Output:

```
SGs FreeDVD StaticBlock v2
SecondPreview FLV 600
All Over The World Click Countoff Preview
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/89876)

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace()` is the function you need. Something like this will do it:

```
$mystring = preg_replace( array( '/^\d+/', '/\.[a-z0-9]+$/', '/[^a-z0-9]/'),
    array('', '', ' '),
    $mystring);
```

I pass in an array with three parts: (1) leading numbers, (2), a literal `.` followed by numbers or letters, then the end of the string, and (3) a catch-all for non-alphanumeric characters. These are replaced by (1) nothing, (2) nothing, and (3) a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$|^[0-9]+/', '', $string);
preg_replace('/[+_-]+/', ' ', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea using `preg_replace`

```
$str = '
5SGs_FreeDVD_StaticBlock_v2.jpg
30SecondPreview_FLV-600.flv
All Over The World_Click+Countoff_Preview.mp3';

$rx = array(
'~^\d+~m' => "",          // 1.) leading digits (multi-line mode / m-modifier)
'~\.\w+$~m' => "",        // 2.) trailing file types at line-end $ (m-modifier)
'~[[:punct:]]+~' => " "); // 3.) punctuation POSIX

echo "<pre>".preg_replace(array_keys($rx), array_values($rx), $str)."</pre>";
```

*output*:

```
SGs FreeDVD StaticBlock v2
SecondPreview FLV 600
All Over The World Click Countoff Preview
```

It's a bit late, but I love to do that for practice :)